# MonoTouch Linq to XML how to make an IF statement inline

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml, xamarin.ios

Hello I have the following question, is it possible to make an inline if statement?

```
var contact= new XElement("Contact",
                                                new XAttribute("id", id.ToString()),
                                                new XElement("ContactData",
                                                             new XElement("Prefix", person.Prefix),
                                                             new XElement("FirstName", person.FirstName)
                                                );
```

Because sometimes person.x could be null and its bringing me errors.

thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
var contacts = new XElement("Contact",
        new XAttribute("id", id.ToString()),
        new XElement("ContactData",
            new XElement("Prefix", person.Prefix == null ? "" : person.Prefix),
            new XElement("FirstName", person.FirstName == null ? "" : person.FirstName));
```

The syntax is `(condition ? truevalue : falsevalue)`

Comment: person.Prefix == null ? "" : person.Prefix  is the same as  person.Prefix ?? ""   It used to be a pain to google for if you don't know the name (null-coalescing operator) :)

Comment: the you should just move the condition to the beginning of the statement whether creating or not the new XElement

Comment: If empty tags are not okay, what do you want to accomplish then?

Answer (score 0):

What is it you want to happen if `person.x` is `null`?

If you want it to default the value, you could wrap the `person.Prefix` (for example) in a method that takes the string and returns either the string or some acceptable default.

Otherwise there's this:

```
string x = null;
string y = x ?? "f";
```

`y` becomes `"f"` if `x` is `null`, otherwise it gets the value of `x`.

Comment: I dont fully understand whats going on here could you explain it? **string y = x ?? "f";** @lan

Comment: `if (x != null) { y = x; } else { y = "f"; }`

Comment: Hi Joe, sixlettervariables gave the expanded version. Sorry, I must slow down when I reply and add useful information. ?? is a C# operator which replaces a null with a value you specify. So y = x ?? "f" says exactly what sixlettervariables said.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) for default values if you don't want them to stay `null`:

```
var contact = new XElement ("Contact",
    new XAttribute ("id", id.ToString ()),
    new XElement ("ContactData",
        new XElement("Prefix", person.Prefix ?? string.Empty),
        new XElement("FirstName", person.FirstName ?? string.Empty)
    )
);
```